# adding image to library in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I've done some research on this issue for the past hour. It should be an easy issue, but I still can't get it to work. I've added an image called IMG_0000.JPG in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Media/DCIM/100APPLE and ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE. People say the easy way out is to drag an image from safari to the library. I did that and it opens the image in safari, but when I try again the image is not there. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they are talking about adding the image from Safari, it is actually adding it in Safari from the simulator.

Open Safari on your iPhone simulator, go open the image you want and make a long press on the image. An option to save the image should appear.

Comment: now this is weird, I did click on save image, relaunch my app and then still nothing there

Comment: and now in my iphone simulator folder I can only see one folder called User

Comment: Yeah, I got that too. Try to open Photos.app, it will rebuild index.

Comment: I don't have any photos.app, you mean iPhoto?

Comment: In the simulator, there's an app called Photos

Comment: Tip: you can drag image to simulator. It'll open Safari.